# The prefix 'xg0' is not defined

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

i have a WCF Workflow Foundation Server.

I tried add query correlation as described in tutorials, so my key is "sm:body()/xg0:User/xg0:PlayerID"

But if i when call receive method i get an exception :
"The prefix 'xg0' is not defined.
Exception Details: System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException: The prefix 'xg0' is not defined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query correlations can get a bit confused at times, the designer leaves room for improvement. Usually the easiest way of solving the problem is deleting the correlation and recreating it. The other option is to open the XAML in the XML editor and fixing the problem that way. But make sure you have a backup copy before you start if you are not used to doing that.